# Messed up geometry when stitching a hand to an arm

Tags: modeling

I tried stitching a hand onto an arm. The results are unusual. I've checked the normals. What could be happening?
[image: Back]

[image: Front]

[image: Back w/ Subsurf]

[image: Front w/ Subsurf]

Comment: This could be infernal faces. Go to wireframe view and face selection and remove the faces in the hand. Another possibility would be double vertices. Hit spacebar and type 'remove doubles' and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Could you also provide wireframe images? It's easier for us to see the problems then. The knuckle area seems to have a whole different resolution than the fingers.

Comment: It was internal faces. Now the hand is fixed and looks much better. There were also internal faces on the fingers, and I fixed that, too. Thanks!